# Could not connect to VM created with Azure command line tools

Tags: azure

I am trying to use the Azure Command Line Tools (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/how-to-guides/command-line-tools/) to create an Ubuntu 12.04 VM.

I am issuing the following commands:

```
azure vm create xxxxxxxxxx.cloudapp.net b39f27a8b8c64d52b05eac6a62ebad85__Ubuntu-12_04_1-LTS-amd64-server-20121218-en-us-30GB azureuser mypassword --location "West Europe"

azure vm endpoint create xxxxxxxxxx 22 22

azure vm start xxxxxxxxxx
```

This seems to create and start the VM successfully.

I try to connect via SSH to the VM using the following command (on Mac OS X)

```
ssh azureuser@xxxxxxxxxx.cloudapp.net
```

However, when I try to SSH into the VM, it seems that password authentication is disabled on the VM as I am getting the following error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I would like to add that connecting via SSH to an Ubuntu VM created trough the Azure Management portal works absolutely fine. This issue only appears when the VM was created through the Azure command line tools.

Has anybody encountered a similar issue and knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `--ssh` switch on your `azure vm create` command to enable ssh. Adding the endpoint has no effect.

According to the [Windows Azure command-line tool for Mac and Linux](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/other-resources/command-line-tools/) documentation you can only add ssh connectivity via the azure cli when the virtual machine is created.

Comment: Great thanks for the link. This is the kind of doc that I was looking for!